# C# What is the best way to RESOLVE the warning compilation "CS8618"

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-warnings, required, c#-12.0

If we declare property like this:

```
public class Cat
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

we get a warning compilation:

> CS8618 - Non-nullable variable must contain a non-null value when
> exiting constructor. Consider declaring it as nullable.

because `Name` property is not initialized.

Imagine, this is mandatory property (business rules say it). We can try to solve it by several ways:

1. Constructor declaration:

a) In ctor directly:

```
public class Cat
{
    public Cat()
    {
        Name = string.Empty;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

b) in property:

```
public class Cat
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

really, both options is the same (syntax sugar).

pros: we can use init of class like `Cat cat = new ();`

cons: property is initialized by 'dummy' value when object is created and will be rewritten. Or (much more major) will not be rewritten by some unknown reasons (e.g. we use automapper and source object had empty value for this field or we forgot to map this field) and in result object will have invalid value (by business rules property can't be empty, cat must have a name)

2. declare field as nullable:

```
public class Cat
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

for me, it's invalid approach (although it's described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/nullable-warnings?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS8618)#nonnullable-reference-not-initialized) as alternative), our business rule says, that `Name` is mandatory and model can't be valid without this property (so, in the best conditions, it should not be even created)

3. Use `required` keyword:

```
public class Cat
{
    public required string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So, it looks like the best (class can't be created without explicit init of `Name` field), but only for the first glance, because it's also 'syntax sugar', which uses only for compilation. So, when we map a property using automapper, we face with the same problem: object can be mapped without this property (or with null value from source object).

So, all of these approach only mask the problem (avoid warning compilation): object can be created with fake (default) value!

Any way to resolve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Assume it's a table in database, make the db column not-nullable, and validate upon the input of source objects (e.g. controller requests)? Or wrap the mapper logic in Cat itself and only allow construting through it, so you can ensure validation after mapping?

Comment: If it is a business requirement that the property be populated then make it part of the business logic. Make the property nullable and then validate it to ensure that it's not null before saving.

Comment: I always go for option 3 (required keyword) if possible. If some library like AutoMapper doesn't understand/follow this keyword, then maybe it's time to change it to an alternative library that does? E.g. Mapperly is an object mapper that works by using source generation, so it also has to follow the rules of the required keyword.

Comment: @jmcilhinney so much code then. I search laconic way to solve this problem. Other way set `Name` in ctor, but there is also so much code and have to enumerate properties in automapper, that leveled out to use Automapper at all

Answer (score 2):

If the property cannot be null, just put it in constructor, so there is no warning and must initialize the class with a valid value.

```
public class Cat
{
    public Cat(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: in this case, if we use Automapper, we have to enumerate many parameters in automapper rules and sense to use automapper leveled out

Comment: if the property can be null when work with automapper, then you have to mark it as nullable , and check it everytime before use.

Comment: but then we have to think about check to not nullable in code, so, it's not clear anything

Comment: that's life, either you make sure it's not null, or you have to check it, and the warning was desinged for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

The null-ability warning is a compile-time warning to remind you to ensure that the property is initialized. IMHO initializing the value to something that is invalid to remove the warning is no better than just ignoring/disabling the warning entirely.

If you want to guard at runtime then you need to implement your code with such a guard, regardless of making the compiler happy. This can either be via update actions rather than setters, or explicit setters and not using auto-properties.

```
public string Name { get; private set; }

public void UpdateName(string name)
{      
    ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(name, nameof(name));
    Name = value;
}
```

or

```
private string _name;
public string Name
{
    get => _name;
    set 
    {
        ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrEmpty(value, nameof(Name));
        _name = value;
    }
}
```

In both cases you should consider having a constructor that initializes all required properties at least, which will satisfy the compiler warning. When it comes to Entity Framework this warning can be a bit of a pain so the pattern I use is to have the constructor with all required fields, but then add a `protected` default constructor for EF to use, and use the `#pragma disable / restore` around it to avoid the warning.

Comment: in this case, if we use Automapper, we have to enumerate many parameters in automapper rules and sense to use automapper leveled out

Comment: If you are mapping a source instance to a destination instance using the `Map(src,dest)` method then you can use the explicit property approach and just tell Automapper which properties in the entity to ignore. If you are using Automapper as a deep-copy factory (`var dest = Mapper.Map<TDest>(src)`) then I believe it should still work but frankly I would just use a typed constructor accepting a source object and assert and copy the values manually.

Comment: what sense to use Automapper then, if we copy the values manually?

Comment: Using something like automapper is fine, but to avoid copying across data you don't want changed you either have to configure it exclusive or inclusive to not copy values it shouldn't.  Automapper will still use explicit property setters if you set those up rather than auto-properties.  Either way the nullable warnings are a compile time reminder, at runtime you still need guards if code results in a null reference.